# Override default behavior of mocked object in SpringBootTest

Tags: java, mockito, spring-boot-test

I am wondering if I can set a default behavior on a mocked object, and override it for some of the tests when using `@SpringBootTest`.

I tried setting the default behavior in a method annotated with `@BeforeEach`, and overriding it in the tests where I need to.
The following code works if I run the `createWithException` test alone, but not when it's part of a test suite.

```
@Disabled
public abstract class RestApiBaseTest extends AbstractSpringBootTest {

    @MockBean(name = "myClassRestTemplate")
    protected RestTemplate apiRestTemplate;

    @Mock
    @Qualifier("myClassProperties")
    HTTPDAOProperties apiProperties;

    @BeforeEach
    public void init() throws Exception {
        //default behavior for every test in a suite
        ResponseEntity r = new ResponseEntity(new HashMap<String, String>(), HttpStatus.ACCEPTED);
        Mockito.when(apiProperties.getUrl()).thenReturn("http://localhost:8080/test");
        Mockito.when(apiRestTemplate.exchange(any(), Mockito.eq(new ParameterizedTypeReference<Map<String, String>>() {}))).thenReturn(r);
    }

}
```

Tests :

```
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
@ActiveProfiles("IC")
public class CreationTest extends RestApiBaseTest {

    @Test
    public void createWithAllInfo() {
        //default behavior not overridden 
        // ...
    }

    @Test
    public void createWithException() {

        //override behavior to throw exception
        APIError mockedApiError = APIError.builder()
                .withHttpCode(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR.value())
                .withError("problem", "1")
                .build();

        APIErrorException apiErrorException = new APIErrorException(mockedApiError);
        Mockito.when(apiRestTemplate.exchange(Mockito.any(), Mockito.eq(new ParameterizedTypeReference<Map<String, String>>() {}))).thenThrow(apiErrorException);

        //...
    }

}
```

When part of a test suite, the behavior doesn't get overriden.

Comment: It looks like the only solution is to anotate the class with @DirtiesContext(classMode = DirtiesContext.ClassMode.AFTER_EACH_TEST_METHOD) to reload the context after each test, but it brings a massive overhead...

Comment: It seems you want to test HTTP calls. you can use https://wiremock.org/ or spring mockMVCServer.